# Am I allowed to remove the watermark of an image applied by a third party not owning the original?

Tags: united-states, copyright

Many widget sellers all have images and diagrams for third parties to use at will.

One company aggregates these widgets and sells them on their website and uses the source companies' images and diagrams, but they place watermarks on those images (and potentially perform other edits like adjusting size, buffer, and background).

I recognize I could download these images and diagrams for myself from the source website, but the aggregating site makes things so much easier.

I understand that if the aggregator site makes their own images and diagrams, taking those would be in violation of copyright, but I'm specifically asking in the case of the aggregator placing their watermark on images that are for public use.

Is it a copyright breach to download these images, remove their watermark, then use them on my own site since they are technically not the owner of the original source material?

I looked [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/32447), but it isn't quite clear that this situation is covered.

Comment: I just found an answer in the related questions here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18786/is-there-liability-for-distributing-someone-elses-copyrighted-material-to-those